# Auto build Actionbarsherlock in Jenkins got error

Tags: android, jenkins, actionbarsherlock

I have several library projects.

1. ActionBarSherlock
2. NineOldAndroid
3. libCommon1
4. libCommon2

libCommon2 reference ActionBarShelock, NineOldAndroid and libCommon1.

And my MainGUI prject is the entrance Project which just reference libCommon2.

I config my Jenkins to build these projects in this order:

1. ActionBarShelock
2. NineOldAndroid
3. libCommon1
4. libCommon2
5. MainGUI

When I tried to build the projects. The first three porjects were built successfully, when it came to libCommon2, there are a several errors point to ActionBarShelock which about field redefinition.

here are the errors:

---

```
-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.

 [echo] Handling aidl files..
 [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
 [echo] ----------
 [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
 [renderscript] No RenderScript files to compile.
 [echo] ----------
 [echo] Handling Resources...
 [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:4: error: Attribute "titleTextStyle" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:5: error: Attribute "subtitleTextStyle" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:6: error: Attribute "background" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:7: error: Attribute "backgroundSplit" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:8: error: Attribute "height" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:9: error: Attribute "divider" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:17: error: Attribute "actionBarTabStyle" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:18: error: Attribute "actionBarTabBarStyle" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:19: error: Attribute "actionBarTabTextStyle" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:20: error: Attribute "actionOverflowButtonStyle" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:22: error: Attribute "actionBarStyle" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:27: error: Attribute "actionBarSplitStyle" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:35: error: Attribute "actionBarWidgetTheme" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:38: error: Attribute "actionBarSize" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:42: error: Attribute "actionBarDivider" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:44: error: Attribute "actionBarItemBackground" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:47: error: Attribute "actionMenuTextAppearance" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:49: error: Attribute "actionMenuTextColor" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:55: error: Attribute "actionModeStyle" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:56: error: Attribute "actionModeCloseButtonStyle" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:58: error: Attribute "actionModeBackground" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:60: error: Attribute "actionModeSplitBackground" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:62: error: Attribute "actionModeCloseDrawable" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:64: error: Attribute "actionModeShareDrawable" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:67: error: Attribute "actionModePopupWindowStyle" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:75: error: Attribute "buttonStyleSmall" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:81: error: Attribute "windowContentOverlay" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:84: error: Attribute "textAppearanceLargePopupMenu" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:87: error: Attribute "textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:91: error: Attribute "textAppearanceSmall" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:93: error: Attribute "textColorPrimary" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:94: error: Attribute "textColorPrimaryDisableOnly" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:95: error: Attribute "textColorPrimaryInverse" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:97: error: Attribute "spinnerItemStyle" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:98: error: Attribute "spinnerDropDownItemStyle" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:106: error: Attribute "listPreferredItemHeightSmall" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:109: error: Attribute "listPreferredItemPaddingLeft" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:111: error: Attribute "listPreferredItemPaddingRight" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:114: error: Attribute "textAppearanceListItemSmall" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:117: error: Attribute "windowMinWidthMajor" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:118: error: Attribute "windowMinWidthMinor" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:123: error: Attribute "dividerVertical" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:125: error: Attribute "actionDropDownStyle" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:126: error: Attribute "actionButtonStyle" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:127: error: Attribute "homeAsUpIndicator" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:128: error: Attribute "dropDownListViewStyle" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:129: error: Attribute "popupMenuStyle" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:130: error: Attribute "dropdownListPreferredItemHeight" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:131: error: Attribute "actionSpinnerItemStyle" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:132: error: Attribute "windowNoTitle" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:133: error: Attribute "windowActionBar" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:134: error: Attribute "windowActionBarOverlay" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:135: error: Attribute "windowActionModeOverlay" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:136: error: Attribute "windowSplitActionBar" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:139: error: Attribute "listPopupWindowStyle" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:143: error: Attribute "activityChooserViewStyle" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:145: error: Attribute "activatedBackgroundIndicator" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:148: error: Attribute "absForceOverflow" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:157: error: Attribute "navigationMode" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:166: error: Attribute "displayOptions" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:175: error: Attribute "title" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:177: error: Attribute "subtitle" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:183: error: Attribute "icon" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:185: error: Attribute "logo" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:191: error: Attribute "backgroundStacked" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:195: error: Attribute "customNavigationLayout" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:199: error: Attribute "homeLayout" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:201: error: Attribute "progressBarStyle" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:203: error: Attribute "indeterminateProgressStyle" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:205: error: Attribute "progressBarPadding" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:208: error: Attribute "itemPadding" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:227: error: Attribute "itemTextAppearance" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:229: error: Attribute "horizontalDivider" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:231: error: Attribute "verticalDivider" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:233: error: Attribute "headerBackground" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:235: error: Attribute "itemBackground" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:237: error: Attribute "windowAnimationStyle" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:239: error: Attribute "itemIconDisabledAlpha" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:241: error: Attribute "preserveIconSpacing" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:250: error: Attribute "initialActivityCount" has already been defined
 [aapt] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Vinson_libactionbarsherlock/workspace/res/values/abs__attrs.xml:257: error: Attribute "expandActivityOverflowButtonDrawable" has already been defined
```

---

I am not sure whether it is from ActionBarShelock or from my Jenkins' configuation. Please help if anyone have any idea about these errors.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled about a similar problem. Another project (aviary.com sdk in my case) seems to have the same attr name in aviary_attrs.xml on line 262. Maybe renaming them fixes the problem?